# Add divs on a scrollbar

Tags: css, angular, scrollbar

[image]Add absolute or fixed divs on a scrollbar.

I can customize scrollbar, but I want to add some divs/areas/buttons on the scrollbar.
I don't want to add scrollbar on a div. I want to add absolute or fixed divs on a scrollbar.
I hope image helps to make clear what I have asked.
Is there any chance to do it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.